# the result of "setfacl --modify" will get reverted after a reboot

Tags: arch-linux, docker, setfacl

A docker, when run for the 1st time, won't do so:

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d
permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.24/containers/json?all=1&filters=%7B%22label%22%3A%7B%22com.docker.compose.config-hash%22%3Atrue%2C%22com.docker.compose.project%3Doxygen%22%3Atrue%7D%7D": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

I'll run this command

```
$ sudo setfacl --modify user:user1:rw /var/run/docker.sock
```

which will resolve the issue. However, after a reboot, the issue will arise again. Why? How to make the change permanent?

Comment: Probably the best is to add your user to the docker group to be sure it has be right rights.      sudo usermod -aG docker user1